# Power BI auto refresh after SSAS process

Tags: report, powerbi, power-bi-report-server, reportmanager

I created a report using `Power BI` and my cube contains only `Year = 2016` data. I place a `Slicer` on my page and it shows only `2016` in his items. Now I `Process` 2017 data and I expected that slicer automatically add 2017 year to slicer, But that didn't happen!

I had to open my report in `Power BI` and press `Refresh` button and the 2017 added to slicer.

[image]

My problem is despite I press `Refresh` button in `Power BI Report Server` but 2017 item didn't added to report slicer.

[image: w]

How this is done dynamically? And I don't have to open the report in `Power BI`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you used `Import` storage mode for your report, and it contain a copy of your data. On contrary, `Live connect` sends any queries directly to the data source and not to a local copy stored with the report itself. The storage mode is set in `Get Data` dialog:

[image]

Unfortunately, it's not directly possible to switch from `Import` to `Live connect`, because with live and DirectQuery modes you have limitations, that doesn't exists in `Import`. If you want to switch the storage mode, you can use the workaround described [here](https://ruiromanoblog.wordpress.com/2018/02/01/convert-a-power-bi-desktop-report-from-import-to-live-query/).

If you decide to stay in `Import` mode, you need to setup a [scheduled refresh](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/report-server/scheduled-refresh) for your dataset.

The refresh button in the report is a bit confusing for me. It doesn't refresh the underlying dataset! There is a separate command for that. When your storage mode is `Import`, a dedicated instance of SSAS tabular is run in the background, which reads the imported copy of the data. This is what is refreshed in this case, not the actual copy of the data to be re-read from the datasource. [This](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Report-Server/What-does-the-refresh-button-really-do/td-p/477740) is one good explanation of what happens.

For more information take a look at [Data refresh in Power BI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/refresh-data) and [Storage mode in Power BI Desktop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-storage-mode).